# Detecting more a word and something else in a batch file using IF

Tags: batch-file

I think that the title is self-explanatory so I'll just paste the code I've thought of.

```
set /p ms=%scmd%
if "%ms%" == "color *" %ms%
if "%ms%" == "title *" %ms%`
```

What I'm trying to do is detect if the user does "color" and something else, detect the "color" part and do the command. The same for "title".

It looks like "*" is not working here and I think there is no other way to do it. Any ideas?

EDIT: Ignore the %scmd% thing.

EDIT 2: Final look of the thingy:

```
set /p ms=%scmd%
echo %ms%|findstr /b /i /L /c:"color " >nul
if not errorlevel 1 %ms% & goto settings
echo %ms%|findstr /b /i /L /c:"title " >nul
if not errorlevel 1 %ms%`
```

Thanks to [Magoo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2128947/magoo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo %ms%|findstr /b /i /L /c:"color " >nul
if not errorlevel 1 %ms%
```

The `echo` sends the string in `ms` to `findstr`, which looks for the `/L` literal string `/c:"this string"` `/b` at the beginning `/i` case-insensitive.
The `>nul` causes the output of `findstr`, which would otherwise be sent to the console to *nowhere*

If the string is found, `errorlevel` will be set to 0, if not, to 1

Since `if errorlevel n` means "if the errorlevel is n **or greater than n** then "if not errorlevel 1` means "if errorlevel is zero"

Comment: Thanks for the fast and useful answer! It's working great now.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test that *the first word* of the user input be one of *several words* in a list, then you may use this method:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Define the list of valid words; enclose each one by / delimiters
set "words=/color/title/"

set /p ms=%scmd%

rem Take the first word in %ms%
for /F %%a in ("%ms%") do (

   rem If such a word is in the list, execute the command
   if "!words:/%%a/=!" neq "%words%" %ms%

)
```

This method works even if the user enter leading spaces (i.e. `"   color 0a"`) and allows to add more commands modifying just one line.

Comment: I was looking for a simple way to do that and I don't want to mess with setlocals nor delayedexpansions because I still don't understand how do they work. Anyways thanks for your response.

Comment: Ok. Just remember that using `find` or `findstr` commands to search text, and using a `|` pipe line, is less efficient. If you do that on _each line_ of a large text file, then the difference in time vs. another method that does not use such features may be huge!

Answer (score 0):

Since the action to take is the same you could use findstr with a regex and conditional execution instead of using errorlevel.

- findstr uses regex by default and a space delimits two regex's with an or condition
- the caret anchors the regex at the begin
- `&&` executes when the previous command had no error (findstr did match)

---

```
set /p ms=%scmd%
Echo:%ms%|findstr /i "^color ^title" >Nul 2>&1 && %ms%
```